# Python SHA512 salted passwords with crypt on MacOS X

Tags: python, hash, osx-yosemite, crypt, sha512

I am trying to generate encrypted password strings, similar to /etc/shadow in Linux. For some reason the output I am getting is different. Any ideas what am I missing and is one has longer than the other (not counting the salt portion)?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import crypt

alg = 6  # SHA512
salt = 'vb1tLY1qiY'
word = 'password'

insalt = '${}${}$'.format(alg, salt)

cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word, insalt)
print cryptWord
```

The output is: `$6FMi11BJFsAc`

If I generate this in Linux like this:

```
mkpasswd --method=sha-512 --salt=vb1tLY1qiY password
```

The output is: `$6$vb1tLY1qiY$WFHTa6CRShEuKg63vuPTYOVRK1oQiM6johIEs2JslF1904VhEdSXlHje74eB4uLXHrKNyZ4bPjSlWpZD6qIo71`

Comment: Cannot duplicate. I ran your python script on 2.7.6 and3.4.3. Both produced the same full output as `mkpasswd`.

Comment: @tdelaney try it in Python 3 on http://repl.it, you get the short answer from `crypt.crypt('password', '$6$vb1tLY1qiY$')`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler wow, you are right. Works fine on my desktop. Color me confused.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler the python `crypt` doc says _Notice that the behavior of this module depends on the actual implementation of the crypt(3) routine in the running system._. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I think the problem is the salt. The documentation says it has to be 2 or 16 characters. The salt here is just 10 characters.

Comment: @munircontractor That's part of it but on repl.it, `crypt.crypt('password', '$6')` also returns `'$6FMi11BJFsAc'`. That implementation is only taking the first two chars as salt and ignoring the rest. By the docs on my system, `$id$salt` is a glibc extension.

Comment: @tdelaney I think I just realized what's happening. The `crypt` function is expecting a glibc extension to run the SHA512 algo, but if it doesn't find a glibc library, it's running the standard DES encryption, which uses only 2 character salts.  The [documentation for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html) does say it chooses the most secure encryption first and then starts falling back to less secure methods. DES is the last in that list. The documentation for Python 2 doesn't even say if it does SHA512 or not. The 13 character output is also consistent with this hypothesis.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. So I'm running the script on my MacOSx 10.10.5 with the latest Macports. I tried both Python 2.7.10 and 3.5, and the output is the same $6FMi11BJFsAc. If I run it in a Kali Linux VM, the output looks correct and it is like mkpasswd. Any ideas why OSx is producing the weird results and if there is something else that needs to be installed? Thanks.

Comment: @user1781482 You need the glibc library for running SHA512. Does your Mac have glibc library installed, and can python access them? I have never worked with Macs so I don't know what the default is for them, but Linux distribs come with glibc installed and configured to work with python and other languages.

Comment: I've been Googling stuff all day and I can't find any information about installing glibc on MacOSx. I already have the latest Xcode with command line tools and Macports, but it appears that this library is not in there for some reason. Does anyone have information on how to get crypt work properly with SHA512 on a Mac? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1781482  Try http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Development/Libraries/GLibC.shtml You might need to read some documentation for custom installs, but running `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install` should do it for most standard systems.

Comment: The one on Softpedia is from 2011. The latest Glibc source can be found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/ but it won't compile on a Mac. The error is this:

configure: running configure fragment for add-on libidn
*** The GNU C library is currently not available for this platform.
*** So far nobody cared to port it and if there is no volunteer it
*** might never happen.  So, if you have interest to see glibc on
*** this platform visit
*** http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/porting.html
*** and join the group of porters

I guess crypt function in Python won't ever work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use passlib. It doesn't come installed as part of python (at least on OS X) but, you can install it via pip.

```
sudo easy_install pip
pip install passlib
python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; import getpass,string,random; print sha512_crypt.using(salt=''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(16)]),rounds=5000).hash(getpass.getpass())"
```

https://gist.github.com/hbeatty/25db5847e7068335681db88248d0deaf

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution that works without installing external software. Should be possible since OSX passwords themselves are sha512 encrypted. Also: if you need sudo to install software on a Mac, that is a clear sign you are on the wrong track, and should try to find an alternative.