# UniFi Contoller password reset

Tags: controller, passwords, localhost, reset

I recently got locked out of my UniFi controller (locally installed) and I had remote access turned off.
The controller is installed on a Windows 10 (20H2) VM. I can get into the VM just fine, but when I try to log into the localhost website, it doesn't like the password I thought I had set.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hunting around and looking at various answers, I was able to put together a set of instructions that worked for me. I thought I would share those here. Please let me know if these don't work on Mac or Linux as I only tested on Windows.

### Mongo

#### Windows, Mac, and Linux:

Find out what version of mongodb the UniFi controller installed:

```
%UserProfile%/Ubiquiti UniFi/Logs
```

The 3rd line of the mongo.log file will show the DB version number, my case it was:

```
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.15
```

Visit https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

On the MongoDB Community Server area, change the version to the closest match to your controller, in my case it was 3.4.24

OS should default to your current OS Windows/Mac/Linux

Select Package type of **zip** as unless you want to install this version of mongo, you only want to run the executable.

Download and unzip

#### CMD/Terminal

Launch CMD/Terminal as Administrator

Navigate into the unziped mongo install folder's sub-folder 'bin' in CMD.
Type:

```
mongo --port 27117

use ace

db.admin.find()
```

Copy the **"_id"** key and value

Copy the **"x_shadow"** key and value

### mkpasswd

#### Linux/Mac:

Next you will need the **whois** package installed in order to access the **mkpasswd** utility

- Ex: For Ubuntu: sudo apt install whois

#### Windows:

Use a WSL linux distro or you can alternately use [Cygwin Utilities](https://cygwin.com/index.html) which has the required [mkpasswd](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html) utility

#### The Salt

The salt for UniFi's mongo install is **9Ter1EZ9$lSt6**

Run:

```
mkpasswd --method=sha-512 --salt=9Ter1EZ9$lSt6 your-new-password
```

Copy the result to a text file

Add the following to the same text file and update the **x_shadow** with the data you just generated:

```
db.admin.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("your-ObjectId-value-string")},{$set: {"x_shadow" : "result-of-mkpasswd-here"}})
```

#### CMD/Terminal

Copy and paste the above into the cmd

#### UniFi Controller

Login to the UniFi controller with your email and new password

Note: you can also update the email or username, but that shouldn't
be required as you will get that information in the dump from running **db.admin.find()**

### Sources used:

- https://www.robsblog.co/2018/10/how-to-reset-unifi-controller-admin-password-without-email-including-32bit/

Note: The site mentioned in Rob's Blog at 'https://quickhash.com/crypt3-sha512-online' doesn't seem to be active
anymore and the similarly named quickhash-gui.org doesn't offer a salt option that I could find.

- https://cwl.cc/2020/10/resetting-a-unifi-controllers-admin-password.html
- [Python SHA512 salted passwords with crypt on MacOS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794479/python-sha512-salted-passwords-with-crypt-on-macos-x)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the instructions from Dan Awesome (below) worked. I had [Unifi running in Docker](https://github.com/jacobalberty/unifi-docker) on an underlying Ubuntu 22.04 OS. I executed `docker exec -it unifi /bin/bash` to ssh into the Docker machine, then these instructions worked as expected. (I did have to install `whois` to get `mkpasswd`.) Thanks!